# How to resolve this UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I need to register a user and use it's email as Username. I am getting this error (UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username) when trying to register on the page. I AM NEW TO DJANGO AND PYTHON

My Code is

forms.py File

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from phonenumber_field.formfields import PhoneNumberField
from django.db import transaction
from .models import User

class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    name                = forms.CharField(max_length=60)
    # Username          = forms.CharField(max_length=15)
    email               = forms.EmailField()

class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
    models      = User
    fields      = ['name','email','password1','password2']
```

views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from .forms import UserRegistrationForm
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            User = form.save()

    else:
        form = UserRegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'users/signup.html', {'form': form})
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    """docstring for User"""
    email       = models.EmailField(verbose_name='Email Address', unique=True)
    name        = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    USERNAME_FIELD      = 'email'
    user_permissions    = None
    groups              = None
    REQUIRED_FIELDS     = []

    def __str__():
        return self.name
```